# Trivial bit of IL does not work under Mono

Tags: mono

I have some .net code that generates an assembly then runs it. It has worked reliably under .net for some time. Under Mono the code works on some non-trivial instances but on others it dies with an illegal IL exception.

When attempting to isolate the problem I cut it down to the point where it just returns a native int. The example works fine under .net and dies under Mono. Reflector says the code is as follows, and this is as expected:

```
.method public hidebysig static native int Main() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldc.i8 4
    L_0009: ret 
}
```

The exception I get is: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in HelloWorldType:Main (): IL_0009: ret

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Run PEVerify on the output assembly.

Comment: It says nothing and returns rc 0 (though I do not run the code by invoking the assembly, it is run just after it is generated by the same code that generated it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess: An `i8` is not considered the same type as a native int. If you want to return a native int, you'd need a `conv.i` in the middle. A native int is 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform but only 4 bytes on a 32-bit platform.

Comment: Good spot ;p Mono is finicky this way I have noted.

Comment: Many thanks. Now I just have the original problem to deal with :-)